# multiple frequencies grounded to same ground bus bar

Tags: electrical-panel

Does the NEC allow me to ground a 50hz and 60 hz load (two separate pieces of equipment) to the same ground bus bar in the main distribution panel?

Comment: How are you getting both 50Hz and 60Hz from a single panel to supply these 2 different pieces of equipment?

Answer (score 3):

### Absolutely not

Two Rules in NEC intersect to cause this.

First, different frequencies are by definition and nature different *services*.  **You can't put two services in the same panel** (unless the panel is specifically listed for that use). That's because you can only use an electrical part according to its labeling and instructions which are part of its *listing* and testing at UL etc.

When a manufacturer submits a device for listing, they include draft labeling and instructions, which they revise if necessary to narrow it down to something UL can test and is willing to list.  "Multiple services" is such an off-the-wall requirement that it is difficult to imagine UL would test panels for that.

Second, your grounds (Equipment Grounding Conductor) for any given circuit must go back to the same panel the circuit comes out of. Particularly look at the ground-retrofit rules, which allow grounds from the same panel to be mixed promiscuously, but not from different panels.   **You can't mix grounds from different panels.**. At least not Equipment Grounding Conductors.  These  different services can and often must use the same Grounding Electrode System, but that join will be *outside* the panels.

Comment: But what about generated from 60 Hz to 50hz because it is a device creating the different frequency they would both be bonded in the same panel and going back to the same grounding electrod.

Comment: @EdBeal Well, if it installs cord-and-plug-connected, like a consumer UPS, step-up transformer or VFD, then it grounds like one. In that case, there's a mini-service inside the UPS or step-up, provisioned at the sockets on its chassis, and it passes through ground from its source (the hardwired wall socket).  But if it were that, OP wouldn't be asking.   Put it another way: if you install 120/240 service, transformer-powered off a factory's internal 480, do you daisychain ground off the 480 service, or do you attach the 120/240 panels separately to grounding electrode system? IME the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get different frequencies would be to generate one or live in an area that has both but I have not heard of that in the U.S. or other areas I have traveled internationaly. If using a variable frequency drive the supply to the drive would not change but the load frequency and voltage will change. If this is what your question is referring to both need to be bonded to the equipment ground at the panel where the VFD is supplied and supplys the load.

Comment: You use a frequency converter. The solid state ones are essentially VFDs with fixed output frequency and voltage. The old way was a motor/generator. A situation which would require this is to test equipment destined for a 50 Hz market. There is also such a converter at every airport gate, since aircraft run on 400 Hz power.

Comment: There is a thin line along Honshū, Japan (the main island) where 50Hz and 60Hz territory have a land border.  If you sited just right, you could coax one of each service out of the power companies.  There may be similar locations in South America... Maybe.

Comment: @user71659, I think that may be what our asker is suggesting.  Unfortunately, they seem to be taking line voltage through the panel to run the converter, then running the power out of the converter back into the supply box.  I'm not sure the reasoning, but it seems like a terrible idea.